# Application shortcut for windows in KDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, window-management

I would like to have a shortcut for several applications that does the following:

- Start the application if it's not yet running.
- Put the application in the foreground if it is in the background.
- Put the next instance of the application in the foreground, if it exists.

I am using Debian with KDE. What is the best way of implementing that?

Answer (score 1):

Broken down into steps, you could first look for a task by name, and run it if its not found:

```
APPID=`pgrep <taskname>`
if [ $APPID == "" ] ; then
    <app-command-with-options>
    exit 0
fi
```

The script will now exit if it has to run the app, otherwise continue by [looking for the windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250757/is-there-a-linux-command-to-determine-the-window-ids-associated-with-a-given-pro) belonging to the task:

```
known_windows=$(xwininfo -root -children|sed -e 's/^ *//'|grep -E "^0x"|awk '{ print $1 }')

for id in ${known_windows}
do
    xp=$(xprop -id $id _NET_WM_PID)
    if test $? -eq 0; then
        pid=$(xprop -id $id _NET_WM_PID|cut -d'=' -f2|tr -d ' ')

        if test "x${pid}" = x${APPID}
        then
            echo "Windows Id: $id"
        fi
    fi
done
```

At this point, the script has run through the list of matching windows. You could simply add after the loop a command to activate the window represented by '$id'; this would switch to the last window in the list and should raise it to the top...

```
xdotool windowactivate $id
```

You can figure out different strategies for selecting windows in a sequence that's useful to you. Also, the script can probably be simplified with more clever use of the `xdotool` command and its search options.